# Curl is not hitting url specified

Tags: ssl, curl

Currently I am on curl version : curl 7.60.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).
I updated the verision and hitting the following url:

```
curl -v http://www.google.com
```

It fails to get response for a linux box.
At the same time if I hit it from windows, with the version curl 7.60.0 (i386-pc-win32), It fetched response.

I would like to know if there is any version instability.

Comment: Can you `ping www.google.com`? Does curl follow redirections, try `-L` What is output?

Comment: @lojza.. Yes I can ping www.google.com. -L is not working as well

Comment: Add `--verbose` to get more info. Did you try another client, like `wget` or `openssl s_client`?

Comment: Already added -v . No response. Did not try any other option.